# inner join and partial matches

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm not sure if the title's correct, so here goes.

The following script returns the correct result: currently *Roy Brown* teaches *Math 101*. *Roy Brown's* TeacherID is *1225*,  but then they later added the prefix *001-* for other purposes.

What I would like to include in the result is some identification that *Roy Brown* did have another course at one point in time, since *Math 101 Old* has *1225*. It doesn't even have to show how many other courses he had; just something that will let me know that there is more than one row in `#coursesCsv`. But the result should remain to 2 rows.

What I *don't want* is to display an extra row for *Roy Brown*, which is why I'm not doing the commented `inner join` (ie. `right(t.teacherid,4) = right(c.teacherid,4)`).

There are no relationships between these two tables since the data in `#coursesCSV` comes from a csv file.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#teacher') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #teacher
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#coursesCsv') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #coursesCsv

create table #teacher
(
    TeacherID varchar(10),
    FullName varchar(30)
)

insert into #teacher select '001-1225', 'Roy Brown'
insert into #teacher select '001-1230', 'Woody Boyd'


create table #coursesCsv
(
    CourseName varchar(30),
    TeacherID varchar(10)
)
insert into #coursesCsv select 'Math 101', '001-1225'
insert into #coursesCsv select 'Math 101 Old', '002-1225'
insert into #coursesCsv select 'History 101', '001-1230'

select t.teacherid, c.coursename from 
#teacher t inner join #coursesCsv c
on t.teacherid = c.teacherid
--on right(t.teacherid,4) = right(c.teacherid,4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a "Group Count" of courses for the same `right(teacherid,4)` within a Derived Table (or a Common Table Expression = WITH) and join to it:

```
select t.teacherid, c.coursename, c.coursecnt
from teacher t 
inner join 
 (
   select 
      teacherid,
      coursename,
      count(*)
      over (partition by right(teacherid,4)) as coursecnt
   from coursesCsv
 ) as c
on t.teacherid = c.teacherid
```